# Fourier transform of the Cosine function with Phase Shift?

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

How can i calculate the Fourier transform of a delayed cosine? I haven't found anywhere how to do that.

This is my attempt in hoping for a way to find it without using the definition:

$$ x(t) = cos(2\pi f_ct -θ) = cos\bigg(2\pi f_c\bigg(t -\frac{θ}{2πf_c}\bigg)\bigg) $$
($f_c$ stands for the fundamental frequency of the signal and $θ$ is the phase shift) Now using the Fourier time-shift property $:$ 
$$ x(t-θ) \longrightarrow X(f)e^{-j2πfθ} $$ 
and knowing the fourier transform of 
$$cos(2πf_ct) = \frac{1}{2}δ(f-f_c)+\frac{1}{2}δ(f+f_c)$$ 
i get:
$$ cos\bigg(2\pi f_c\bigg(t -\frac{θ}{2πf_c}\bigg)\bigg) = \bigg[ \frac{1}{2}δ(f-f_c)+\frac{1}{2}δ(f+f_c) \bigg]e^{-j2πf\frac{θ}{2πf_c}} = $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}δ(f-f_c)e^{-\frac{jfθ}{f_c}} +\frac{1}{2}δ(f+f_c)e^{-\frac{jfθ}{f_c}} $$

Is this a way to find it? If yes can i simplify it further? And what happens with the simplifications when you're given the $f_c$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not taking this approach? $$ x(t) = cos(2\pi f_ct -θ) = cos(2\pi f_ct)cos(θ)-sin(2\pi f_ct)sin(θ)$$

Comment: This seems harder to find the Fourier transform. Why not complete that and add as the answer?

Comment: What is the transform for $cos(2\pi f_c t)$?

Comment: It's right there. I have wrote it.. Do you see it? I will write it in one whole line, just so it's better to see.

Comment: You just need to multiply the cos and sin transforms by the phase correction. It looks like what you got is the right result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although the question is old, I would like to provide a solution since recently I have been asked a similar question.

Fourier transform gives the locations and the (complex) amplitudes of the exponential,i.e. $e^{jwt}$, terms. By using the Euler identity $cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{j\theta}+e^{-j\theta}}{2}$ Fourier transform of $cos(wt)$ and $sin(wt)$ can be found. This is due to the fact that $F(e^{jw_0t})=2\pi\delta(w-w_0)$.

Thus the Fourier transform of shifted cosine $x(t)=cos(w_0t-\theta)$ is
$$
cos(w_0t-\theta)=\frac{e^{j(w_0t-\theta)}+e^{-j(w_0t-\theta)}}{2} \\
\rightarrow F(cos(w_0t-\theta))=F(\frac{e^{j(w_0t-\theta)}+e^{-j(w_0t-\theta)}}{2})\\
=\frac{F(e^{j(w_0t-\theta)})+F(e^{-j(w_0t-\theta)})}{2} \\
=\frac{e^{-j\theta}F(e^{jw_0t})+e^{j\theta}F(e^{-jw_0t})}{2} \\ 
=\frac{e^{-j\theta}2\pi\delta(w-w_0)+e^{j\theta}2\pi\delta(w+w_0)}{2} \\ 
=\pi(e^{-j\theta}\delta(w-w_0)+e^{j\theta}\delta(w+w_0))
$$