# Fourier transform of phase shifted sinusoid

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

Lets say I have a cosine function

$f(t) = Acos(\omega_0t) $.

I find the Fourier transform $\mathfrak{F}[f(t)] = \frac{A}{2}\left [ \delta (\omega - \omega_0 )  + \delta (\omega + \omega_0 )\right ]$ which is two delta spikes symmetric about zero at $\omega_0$ and $-\omega_0$. I think this is correct.

Now, if I phase shift $f(t) $ to get

$f_s(t) = Acos(\omega_0t+\theta)$

my intuition tells me that the $\mathfrak{F}[f_s(t)] = \mathfrak{F}[f(t)]$ because the phase shift should not impact the frequency content of the signal.

However, when I do the work, I get the following:

$f_s(t)=\frac{A}{2}\left [ e^{i(\omega_0t+\theta)}+e^{-i(\omega_0t+\theta)}\right ]$  (Euler's formula)

So,

$\mathfrak{F}[f_s(t)]=\frac{A}{2}\left [ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega_0t+\theta)}e^{-i\omega t}dt + \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i(\omega_0t+\theta)}e^{-i\omega t}dt\right ]$

$\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\frac{A}{2}e^{i\theta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega_0-\omega)t}dt+\frac{A}{2}e^{-i\theta}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i(\omega_0+\omega)t}dt$

$\, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=Acos(\theta)\left [\delta(\omega+\omega_0) + \delta(\omega-\omega_0) \right ]$

And thus,

$\mathfrak{F}[f_s(t)] \neq \mathfrak{F}[f(t)] $ which goes against my intuition.

Is the math wrong or is my intuition wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, both the intuition and the analysis have flaws.  Please see the posted solution and please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define the Foruier Transform of $f$ to be

$$\mathscr{F}\left(f(t)\right)(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt$$

then the Foruier Transform of $f(t+t_0)$ is

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left(f(t+t_0)\right)(\omega)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t+t_0)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-i\omega t_0}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{e^{-i\omega t_0}\mathscr{F}\left(f(t)\right)(\omega)} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

This general result shows that a time-shift transforms to a phase multiplication.

Now, if $f(t)=A\cos \omega_0t$, then its Fourier Transform is given by

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left(A\cos \omega_0t\right)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty A\cos (\omega_0t)\,e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty A\left(\frac{e^{i\omega_0t}+e^{-i\omega_0t}}{2}\right)\,e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac A2\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega+\omega_0)t}\,dt+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\,dt\right)\\\\
&=\frac A2\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}2\pi \delta(\omega+\omega_0)+\frac{1}{2\pi}2\pi \delta(\omega-\omega_0)\right)\\\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac A2\left(\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+ \delta(\omega-\omega_0)\right)} \tag 2\\\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, if $f(t)=A\cos (\omega_0 t+\theta)=A\cos (\omega_0 (t+t_0))$, where $t_0=\theta /\omega_0$, then we see that this added phase is tantamount to a time shift.  Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left(A\cos (\omega_0t+\theta)\right)&=\frac A2e^{-i\theta \omega/\omega_0}\left(\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+ \delta(\omega-\omega_0)\right)\\\\
&=\frac A2\left(e^{i\theta}\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+ e^{-i\theta}\delta(\omega-\omega_0)\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\mathscr{F}\left(A\cos (\omega_0t+\theta)\right)=\frac A2\left(e^{i\theta}\delta(\omega+\omega_0)+ e^{-i\theta}\delta(\omega-\omega_0)\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. What is the physical significance of the $e^{i\theta}$ term being multiplied by the infinite delta spike?

Also, why does the $\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}$ term disappear in your final line?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The reason that the $\omega/\omega_0$ terms simplify is due to the "sifting" property of the Dirac Delta.  In general, we have $$f(x)\delta(x-a)=f(a)\delta(x-a)$$Here, we have $x=\omega$, $a=\pm \omega_0$, and $f(x)=e^{-i\theta x/a}$.

Comment: @MarkViola: I think it should be

${\mathscr{F}\left(A\cos (\omega_0t+\theta)\right)=\frac A2\left(e^{i\theta}\delta(\omega-\omega_0)+ e^{-i\theta}\delta(\omega+\omega_0)\right)}$

Comment: @Meet And why do you believe that to be the case?  It is not, in fact, the case.  The posted solution is correct given the definition of the Fourier Transform as defined herein.

Comment: Using the Euler's Identity
\begin{align}
Acos(w_0t+\theta)&=\frac{A}{2}\bigg[e^{j(w_0t+\theta)}+e^{-j(w_0t+\theta)}\bigg]\\
&=\frac{A}{2}e^{j\theta}e^{jw_0t}+\frac{A}{2}e^{-j\theta}e^{-jw_0t}
\end{align}
So on taking Fourier transform
\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}[cos(w_0t+\theta)]&=\frac{A}{2}e^{j\theta}\mathscr{F}[e^{jw_0t}]+\frac{A}{2}e^{-j\theta}\mathscr{F}[e^{-jw_0t}]\\ 
&=A\pi e^{j\theta}\delta(w-w_0)+A\pi e^{-j\theta}\delta(w+w_0)\\ 
&=A\pi\bigg\{e^{j\theta}\delta(w-w_0)+e^{-j\theta}\delta(w+w_0)\bigg\}
\end{align}
Do correct me if I'm making mistake.

Comment: @Meet The FT of $e^{i\omega_0 t}$ is $\delta(\omega+\omega_0)$ as I have defined the FT herein.  Please read more carefully.

Comment: @Mark: $\mathscr{F}[e^{jw_0t}] = 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0)$ and $\mathscr{F}[e^{-jw_0t}] = 2\pi\delta(\omega+\omega_0)$

Please follow the links

1. https://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/complexexponential.php
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311835/270251

Comment: @Meet READ the definition of the FT that I am using here!!!!!!  Here $$\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\omega)\equiv \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{\color{blue}{+}i\omega t}\,dt\ne \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{\color{red}{-}i \omega t}\,dt $$Note the signs of the exponent are opposite and note the presence of $1/2\pi$ in the former and NOT in the latter.

Comment: @Meet I do not have time to "discuss in chat."  What on earth do you not understand?  There are several conventions for the definition of a FT [SEE HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions).

Comment: @MarkViola: Sorry I don't think myself to be that smart enough, I don't want to offend you. But I think the problem may be with the symbolic convention. Even if it may be the result should be the same.

Comment: No!  The result will NOT be the same.  There is NOT a single convention for the FT.  Given any one convention, the inverse transform will be defined uniquely.  Please do some reading here before you continue further.

Comment: What can you comment about this then
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2217502/270251

Comment: @MarkViola: you can see in the Wikipedia page you've shared the result of $\mathscr{F}[e^{jw_0t}]$

Comment: That convention differs since (1) the sign on the exponent is opposite of the one I used and (2) there is no factor of $1/(2\pi)$ whereas my convention uses that factor.  BUT I already alerted you to this fact several comments ago.  PLEASE READ and try to understand simple changes in convention here.  Now, I have no more time to go back and forth with you until you've thoroughly read more about this.  I provided a Wiki reference.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. If you want another way of looking at it you can use the fact that cos(a+b)= cos(a)cos(b)-sin(a)sin(b).

However, I think a more interesting thing to note is that if you look at the average value of $\mathfrak{F}[f_s]$ (and by average value I mean the root mean square), then you end up with $\mathfrak{F}[f].