# What is the fourier transform of cos($\omega x - \theta$)? They differ in phase and amplitude of $2*\pi$.

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

What is the Fourier transform of cos($\omega x - \theta$)?
I have two versions of the transformationa and they do not agree. Can anyone help me understand what the issue is here?

version 1: $$F(cos(\theta)) = 0.5 [(\delta (f_0-f) + \delta(f_0+f))]$$
Then using the time shift formula, I got 
$$cos(\omega x - \theta) = e^{-i\omega\frac{\theta}{\theta_o}}F(cos(\theta))$$

version 2:
it is from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407250/fourier-transform-of-the-cosine-function-with-phase-shift)

Comment: Both answers may well be correct, because there are multiple definitions of Fourier transform, which differ by normalization:  one can integrate against $e^{-itx}$, or $e^{-\pi itx}$, or $e^{-2\pi itx}$, and the factor in front of integral also varies.